# Lookup in array, return same row, two columns to the left

Tags: google-sheets, lookup, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Topic says it all.  I have Sheet 1 with a column of numbers.  I have Sheet 2 with 100 columns and 100 rows of numbers.  I want to Lookup a value on Sheet 1 in the array on Sheet 2 and return a value from the array on Sheet 2 that is in the same row, but two columns left from the value.

Example

```
ABCDE
12345
67890
```

If my value on Sheet 2 is 4, I want to return 2.

I've tried to figure out the Lookup function without success.

```
=index(A2,'Weekly Summary'!A52:LR106,'Weekly Summary'!A52:LR106)
```

I've tried fooling around with column() without success.

I keep getting Parse errors, or Out of Range errors.  I can't even figure out how the base function works.  It never seems to return anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

Sample Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1607mFQShPpo0Hv--4oYANQvThSszS32yE3KZc_YwqmU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, {
 Array!C1:C,Array!A1:A;
 Array!D1:D,Array!B1:B;
 Array!E1:E,Array!C1:C}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]